# Create multiple groups of clusters of different colors

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, markerclusterer

It is necessary that several clusters of groups of markers have different colors. For example, the gray markers are combined in grey circle - cluster, yellow - in yellow, and so on.
Here

```
.marker-cluster-small {
background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-small div {
background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 0.6);
}

.marker-cluster-medium {
background-color: rgba(241, 211, 87, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-medium div {
background-color: rgba(240, 194, 12, 0.6);
}

.marker-cluster-large {
background-color: rgba(253, 156, 115, 0.6);
}
.marker-cluster-large div {
background-color: rgba(241, 128, 23, 0.6);
}
```

Specifies the colors for all the clusters. But how to make different colors for different clusters?
For example,

```
var groupGrey = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var groupRed = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var groupYellow = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
var groupBlue = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [`iconCreateFunction`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) option and its [default implementation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/7da6fb2ad2b491d949ebd59c1b854e96f02f6c6f/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L753-L766).